# how to pass parameter value into query in spring boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I made a custom query in JPA spring boot and I want to pass parameters as dynamic to the query, but it doesn't work well.

This is the query:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer>{

    @Query(value = "select * from customer.customer_tbl"
                   + "where firstname like '%:keyword%';", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Customer> findByKeyword(@Param("keyword") String keyword);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work well". Do you get an error message`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `'%:keyword%'` is a string literal so param inside is not replaced.

Use `CONCAT('%',:keyword,'%')`

```
@Query(value = "select * from customer.customer_tbl where firstname like CONCAT('%',:keyword,'%');", nativeQuery = true)
List<Customer> findByKeyword(@Param("keyword") String keyword);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer>{

        @Query(value = "select * from customer.customer_tbl where firstname like CONCAT('%', :keyword, '%');", nativeQuery = true)
        List<Customer> findByKeyword(@Param("keyword") String keyword);
    }
```

Comment: Don't copy paste exsisting answer and code only answer is not a good way to answer.

Comment: didn't copy paste the answer. It just the matter of time. Same time 2 same answer comes up. And unfortunately my answer was second one.